# Calculating odds ratios and respective confidence intervals for multilevel multinomial logistic regression using brm package

Tags: r, brms

I am predicting a 4 category variable using a multinomial regression and allowing intercepts to vary by country. Is there a way to calculate odds ratios and their confidence intervals for each variable (var 1, var 2 and var 3) using the brm package (or another package)?

Model:

```
model = brm(outcome ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + (1 | country), data, family=categorical(link="logit"), control=list(adapt_delta=0.95))
```

`summary(model)` yields a table like this:

[image]

Odds ratios for a given variable (e.g., var1) are obtained by exponentiating the Estimate column. How can I get the confidence interval for these odds ratios?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You can exponentiate confidence intervals like estimates (`exp(confint(model))` or something similar).

Comment: @T.E.G. Thank you. Unfortunately, this does not work on `model`.

Comment: @EML You are welcome, try `exp(fixef(model))`